# Magento : How to Implement Automatic Related Products and Category Based Upsell Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, database

We have 5000 products at our webstore. We can not use magento default feature related products & upsell, cross-sell products. Is there any customize code or modules  which can implement to display automatic related products and category based up-sell & cross-sell products? We are using magento 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Commercial extension available for set up related, cross sell & up sell products automatically.

You can also check free community extensions below:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/related-products-manager.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mtoo-related-automatic-related-products.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is a nice extension to automate your cross-sell and upsell

[https://amasty.com/automatic-related-products-for-magento-2.html](https://amasty.com/automatic-related-products-for-magento-2.html?a=createswowtech)